# Compare node_modules for each releases

Tags: compare, node-modules

Looking for a way to compare package changes between releases.

I need a script or something that when run will show the difference (what packages are new, deleted or updated) between master tagged releases, by comparing the node_modules.

List with all changed or new packages/modules within tree of node_modules.

Comment: Have you tried writing this functionality yourself? If so, what issues did you run into?

Comment: @ihatecsv honestly I didn't, I thought is impossible not be out there something for it, how are people reporting this changes to ...legal if the case or wherever? I am going to start now myself to do it now and if nothing ready made shows up ... will come back with my solution ;)

Comment: I am not sure why I got a vote down, this is not so trivial, I found this package: https://github.com/davglass/license-checker that makes a nice report for one version, maybe can be done for previous one and then I just need 2 compare the reports, between the results with all npm_modules with their versions...

Comment: I actually need something like: https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/package-diff but for full node_modules scan

Answer (score 0):

just came back from holiday, so this is the way I attempted a solution:

```
const checker = require('license-checker')
const compareVersions = require('compare-versions')
const rimraf = require('rimraf')
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api')

const { exec } = require('child_process')

// An access token (from your Slack app or custom integration - xoxp, xoxb)
const token =
  'xoxp-3712510934-8544rv58640-699363584817-a66630cfebf2f81e59478c3f8u0e178b'
const channel = 'where_to_post_report'

let prevReleasePackets
let currReleasePackets

function comparerVersion(otherArray) {
  return current =>
    otherArray.filter(other => other.name === current.name).length === 0
}

function comparerVersionNo(otherArray) {
  return current =>
    otherArray.filter(
      other =>
        other.name === current.name &&
        compareVersions(other.version, current.version) === -1
).length === 0
}

function mapToData(libs) {
  return Object.keys(libs)
    .filter(key => key.indexOf('sm-web') === -1 && key.indexOf('debug') === -1)
    .map(key => {
      const lib = libs[key]
      const name = lib.name
        .replace(/@/g, '_')
        .replace(/\./g, '_')
        .replace(/\//g, '_')
      const version = lib.version.replace(/@/g, '_').replace(/\//g, '_')
      return {
        name,
        version,
      }
    })
}

function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property]
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = []
    }
    acc[key].push(obj.version)
    return acc
  }, {})
}

function getPackets(path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    checker.init(
      {
        start: path,
        production: true,
        customFormat: {
          name: '',
          version: '',
        },
      },
      (err, packages) => {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error
          console.log(err)
          reject(err)
        } else {
          // The sorted package data
          const packagesReduced = groupBy(mapToData(packages), 'name')
          const higerVerionList = []
          Object.keys(packagesReduced).forEach(key => {
            const versions = packagesReduced[key]
            const descVersions = versions.sort(compareVersions).reverse()
            higerVerionList.push({ name: key, version: descVersions[0] })
          })
          resolve(higerVerionList)
        }
      }
    )
  })
}

function clonePrevious(tag) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(
      `git clone https://bitbucket.path_to_repo.git prevVersion && cd prevVersion && git checkout tags/${tag} && yarn && cd ..`,
      async (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.warn(error)
          reject(error)
        }
        if (stdout) {
          const prevPacks = await getPackets('./prevVersion')
          resolve(prevPacks)
        } else {
          resolve(stderr)
        }
      }
    )
  })
}

async function sendReportToSlack(report) {
  const web = new WebClient(token)
  const res = await web.chat.postMessage({
    channel,
    text: report,
  })

  // `res` contains information about the posted message
  console.log('Report sent: ', res.ts)
}

const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
})

console.log('Deleting prevVersion folder')

rimraf('prevVersion', async () => {
  console.log('Done deleting prevVersion folder')

  readline.question(
    `What's the version tag for previous release?`,
    async tag => {
      console.log(`Start cloning and shit the release ${tag}!`)
      readline.close()

      prevReleasePackets = await clonePrevious(tag)

      currReleasePackets = await getPackets('./')

      const update = currReleasePackets.filter(
        comparerVersionNo(prevReleasePackets)
      )

      const deleted = prevReleasePackets.filter(
        comparerVersion(currReleasePackets)
      )

      const newPacks = currReleasePackets.filter(
        comparerVersion(prevReleasePackets)
      )

      const slackMessage =
        `*Packages changes from ${tag}*:\n\n` +
        `*--Updated--*: ${JSON.stringify(
          update
        )},\n\n *--Deleted--*: ${JSON.stringify(
          deleted
        )} \n\n *--New--*: ${JSON.stringify(newPacks)}`

      await sendReportToSlack(slackMessage)
    }
  )
})
```